# Why does not ionic serve run?

Tags: ionic5, angular11

I am getting this error while running ionic serve :

```
[ng] An unhandled exception occurred: The target entry-point "@ionic-native/splash-screen" has missing dependencies:
```

[ng]  - @ionic-native/core
[ng] See "C:\Users\RACHED\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-VPGMIS\angular-errors.log" for further details.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 127).

```
    The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

and this is

[app.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb28I.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAohA.png)

[ionic info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIWOU.png)

Comment: Please post code and error message as text, not as image links.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just have to uninstall older version and install new one using this:

```
 npm uninstall -–save @ionic-native/core
 npm install –-save @ionic-native/core@latest
```

and this will work

Comment: I do it but is still the same problem , I think there is problem in app.component.ts

Comment: can you share your complete code or anything which make more sense ?
because it's look nothing wrong in app.component.ts

Comment: when i delete in app.component.ts(Platform, SplashScreen and StatusBar) and initializeApp the ionic serve is working and it does not working when i keep them

Comment: yes, as I mentioned in my answer the issue is with your version of @ionic-native/splash-screen and @ionic-native/core version, that's why it's throw this error, please share your code or package.json and run ' ionic info ' cmd and send it's output screenshot otherwise i can't able to help you :/

Comment: in my case after npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/core and trying to run the core@latest  got dependency error and not able to install so I tried 
npm install –-save @ionic-native/core@latest --force 
it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the latest version of ionic-native/core

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/core@latest
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).